# Blocking access from server name

Tags: wordpress, apache

Hi I'm hardening a WordPress site that uses Apache for the web server. I want to block access from servername.admin.company.com. I tried editing HTACCESS per another answer I saw here, but the site started 500'ing from https://domainname.com. There are a ton of security issues, and we decided the best way to handle it is to just block access completely since no one really needs to access it that way.

Here's my vhosts file:

```
'  <Directory "/var/www/directory">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    Require not host servername.admin.company.com
  </Directory>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site.com
  ServerAlias www.site.com

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/directory"

  # Enable HSTS (tell browsers to use only HTTP)
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload;"

  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule "^(.*/)?\.git/" - [F,L]
  RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName business.site.com
  ServerAlias subdomain.site.com
 ServerAlias www.business.site.com

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/directory"

  # Enable HSTS (tell browsers to use only HTTP)
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload;"

  <Directory "/var/www/site">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule "^(.*/)?\.git/" - [F,L]
  RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/site-requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName business.site.com
  ServerAlias directory.site.com
 ServerAlias www.subfolder.site.com

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/sitefolder"

  # Enable HSTS (tell browsers to use only HTTP)
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload;"

  <Directory "/var/www/sitefolder">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule "^(.*/)?\.git/" - [F,L]
  RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/sitefolder-requests.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/sitefolder-error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in various ways, `iptables`, `.htaccess`, etc.

Please visit this URL, what you need to do is well documented there:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/access.html

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I'm trying to use .htaccess. I must not be getting the syntax right. Here it is:

`<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not host servername
</RequireAll>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`